# Create a python dataframe using a conditional groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have below data:

```
year code   value  
2003  A      12  
2003  B      11  
2003  C      12  
2004  A      14  
2004  B      15  
2004  C      13  
2004  E      16  
2005  A      9  
2005  B      18  
2005  C      16  
2005  F      8  
2005  G      19
```

**I WANT TO RETAIN ONLY THOSE CODES THAT ARE PRESENT FOR EVERY YEAR.**

From the above dataframe I need to extract all the rows that have codes appear in the years (2003, 2004, 2005). Which means I should have a new df with 9 rows for codes A, B and C. I tried using groupby and isin() but unable to get exactly what I need.

Comment: Show us your expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

**Option 1**

```
In [647]: codes = pd.crosstab(df.year, df.code).replace({0: np.nan}).dropna(axis=1).columns

In [648]: df.query('code in @codes')
Out[648]:
   year code  value
0  2003    A     12
1  2003    B     11
2  2003    C     12
3  2004    A     14
4  2004    B     15
5  2004    C     13
7  2005    A      9
8  2005    B     18
9  2005    C     16
```

**Option 2**

```
In [657]: codes = df.groupby(['year', 'code']).size().unstack().dropna(axis=1).columns

In [658]: df[df.code.isin(codes)]
Out[658]:
   year code  value
0  2003    A     12
1  2003    B     11
2  2003    C     12
3  2004    A     14
4  2004    B     15
5  2004    C     13
7  2005    A      9
8  2005    B     18
9  2005    C     16
```

Comment: I am not sure what this, or the other answer is doing, but my guess is it's better

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ -- So what I 'guessed' was, OP needs set of codes that at present in all/given years.

Comment: How hard would it have been to _say_ that from the start, I wonder 

Comment: @Zero - you got the question correct. Much simpler and easier code :) By the way I used option - 2 (to be clear..!)

Answer (score 2):

Without `groupby`

```
df.set_index(['year','code']).unstack().dropna(axis=1).stack().reset_index()
Out[528]: 
   year code  value
0  2003    A   12.0
1  2003    B   11.0
2  2003    C   12.0
3  2004    A   14.0
4  2004    B   15.0
5  2004    C   13.0
6  2005    A    9.0
7  2005    B   18.0
8  2005    C   16.0
```

Comment: I would love with shorter code but this did not work for me :( . I get an error "Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape.

Comment: @Techflu It should be work :-) Base on your sample data , unless you have multiple key in code

Comment: I will try again and get back. Maybe other columns in my dataset are messing it up. I will slice it further and test your code.

Comment: it works for the exact dataset as above but even if I slice my dataset to 3 columns it throws me that error I described earlier. I believe it is something to do with the index columns I had kept.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need filtering by [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html), but if want dynamically get all values which are in all years use `reduce`:

```
s = df.groupby('year')['code'].apply(list)

from functools import reduce
a = reduce(lambda x, y: set(x) & set(y), s)
print (list(a))
['C', 'A', 'B']

df = df[df['code'].isin(list(a))]
print (df)
   year code  value
0  2003    A     12
1  2003    B     11
2  2003    C     12
3  2004    A     14
4  2004    B     15
5  2004    C     13
7  2005    A      9
8  2005    B     18
9  2005    C     16
```

Comment: I say inefficient in the limited context of the problem described here. This might in fact solve OP's actual problem, but we'll never know what it is since they never made it clear. Based on this limited context there are 10 equally good solutions to the problem. Highly vexing.

Comment: Also, ["hi", "thanks" and "welcome" are all noise](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1):

You can also try a [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#the-query-method-experimental)-based method.

```
df.query("2005 >= year >= 2003 and code in ['A', 'B', 'C']")


    year    code    value
0   2003    A       12
1   2003    B       11
2   2003    C       12
3   2004    A       14
4   2004    B       15
5   2004    C       13
7   2005    A       9
8   2005    B       18
9   2005    C       16
```